# Variations of Dirichlet's theorem on Diophantine approximation

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, diophantine-approximation

Dirichlet's theorem on Diophantine approximation:

For any real number $x$, for integer $N>0$, there exists integers $a$ and $b>0$ with $(a,b)=1$ such that $b\leq N$ and $$|x-\frac a b|<\frac{1}{b(N+1)}.$$

Let $c$ be a fixed positive integer. Is there any version of Dirichlet's theorem to make the following restriction?

version 1) $c|b$

version 2) $(b,c)=1$

Comment: 1) and 2) are contradictory. Did you mean c divides a?

Comment: I mean 1) and 2) are two kinds of restrictions respectively. Obviously 1) and 2) will not exist at the same time...

Answer (score 2):

If $p/q$ and $r/s$ are consecutive convergents of the continued fraction for $x$, then $(tp+ur)/(tq+us)$ is a fairly good approximation to $x$, and you may be able to choose small numbers $t$ and $u$ such that $tq+us$ meets your criteria. See Robert Baggenstos, Ein Beitrag zu den diophantischen Approximationen reeller Zahlen, Elem. Math. 60 (2005) 154-170, MR2188009 (2006g:11140).